# Globally search and replace the path of images referenced?

Tags: html, regex, replace, grep

I have various images that are referenced as such:

```
src="http://myblog.files.example.com/2011/08/image-1.jpg"
src="http://myblog.files.example.com/2010/05/image-2.jpg"
src="http://myblog.files.example.com/2012/01/image-3.jpg"
```

As you can see the only thing that changes in the image paths are the numbers (dates) at the end. What I'd like to do is simply change the path for all images to something like:

```
/sites/default/files/blog-images/
```

... so they would all be like:

```
 src="/sites/default/files/blog-images/image-1.jpg"
 src="/sites/default/files/blog-images/image-2.jpg"
 src="/sites/default/files/blog-images/image-3.jpg"
```

I am wondering if there is a way to do this using regular expressions or some other method? There are hundreds of images all with different numbers in the path so doing this manually is not ideal.

complete sample line of code:

```
<a href="http://myblog.files.example.com/2011/07/myimage-1.jpg">
<img class="alignright size-medium wp-image-423" title="the title" src="http://myblog.files.example.com/2011/07/myimage-1.jpg" alt="the alt" width="300" height="199" />
</a>
```

Comment: Are you wanting to do this on the fly or change the source?

Comment: Do you want root-relative paths, as your output seems to show? And are you wanting to use PHP (server-side) or JavaScript (client-side)?

Comment: It's a one time thing that I am going to exectute on an XML file. In other words it's a hard coded file that I just need to touch once and will never need to do this again or on the fly. So I am thinking my text editor's search and replace (BBedit) can handle regular expressions but if there is a better way to do it, I am open.

Comment: I do want to convert to root relative paths. The original path has http in it. I will update the code above, I am guessing that could be important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
src="http:\/\/myblog.files.example.com/\d{4}/\d{2}/([^\s]+)"
```

Searches and captures the image file names in `$1`.  Now you can do a replace with `/sites/default/files/blog-images/$1`

If your editor doesn't support ranges then you'll need to repeat `\d`.

```
src="http:\/\/myblog.files.example.com/\d\d\d\d/\d\d/([^\s]+)"
```

http://regexr.com?30o8e

Comment: I think I like this but I realized that I have to target the tag: `src="`.  Is there a way to add that on? I've updated my code.

Comment: Why do you need to target src? It does the same replacement with or without src=".  If you really want to, just add `src="` before http.

Comment: Yes it does but there's also an href which gets targeted too by doing it this way. (The href is the same as the image path). I don't really care about the href though as for now I just need to change the image src.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I think the issue is with BBedit as it works fine on regexr.com. Going to mark as answered / upvoted as you gave me a way to do it.  I'll have to figure out why BBedit is not working.

Answer (score 0):

A simple sed one liner can do the trick :

This one to test :

```
sed -r 's@http://myblog.files.example.com/[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/@/sites/default/files/blog-images/@g' FILE
```

This one to change the file

```
sed -ri 's@http://myblog.files.example.com/[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/@/sites/default/files/blog-images/@g' FILE
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do what you are trying to do. Since you tagged "grep" in this post and did not specify any particular programming language, I am going to assume that you want to use UNIX.

First, test out this command:

```
find . -type f | sed 's/\.\/\([0-9]\{4\}\/[0-9]\{2\}\/\)\(.*\)/mv & sites\/default\/files\/blog-images\/\2/'
```

It will print out a list of "mv" commands that will be executed, and if it works how you want it do, you can pipe this into `sh` like so:

```
find . -type f | sed 's/\.\/\([0-9]\{4\}\/[0-9]\{2\}\/\)\(.*\)/mv & sites\/default\/files\/blog-images\/\2/' | sh
```